# Wordpress add function to functions.php that only fires on login

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Updated Solution Attempt:

```
function identify_user( $user_login, $user ) {
    $user_obj = json_encode(array("user_id"=>$user->ID,"user_email"=>$user->user_email));
    $curl = curl_init("myApp.com/endpoint");
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$user_obj);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close( $curl );
    if(curl_error($result)) {  echo'<pre>';var_dump($user);echo'</pre>';die();}
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'identify_user', 10, 2);
```

This function works when I replace wp_login with wp_enqueue scripts, but I cannot seem to get it working with wp_login.

Comment: I just noticed, that `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is using an undefined variable as it's first parameter.

Comment: i'm now getting curl error 51 ssl no alternative certificate matches my endpoint. no idea why it worked the one time!

Comment: lesson learned - heroku apps don't have a www. !

Comment: Haha, so the curl worked?

Comment: yea everything had been working since the $user object was made available with the action hook. i just had www. in my url. now onto figuring out how to get product details on add to cart! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581802/woocommerce-add-to-cart-send-product-data-to-3rd-party-api

Comment: Haha, well great. I'll try and look that one over when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're problem is with <del>`wp_get_current_user()`</del> `curl`. If you're in WordPress you often don't need to use the curl library directly. WP has a built in HTTP API implemented by the `WP_Http` class. Even that though is probably lower than you need to go. I'd suggest trying the [`wp_safe_remote_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_remote_post/) function to do POST to your endpoint. The first parameter is the URL you want to post to and the second is an optional array of args to modify the request. [A list of all accepted $args can be found here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Http/request/#parameters).

As for `wp_get_current_user()`, you shouldn't need that either because your callback is provided two arguments. The first is the username and the second contains a `WP_User` object (the same object returned by `wp_get_current_user()`). The documentation for the hook [can be found here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login).

Try this (original snippet was moved to the bottom of this answer):

```
function identify_user( $user_login, $user ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ):
    $_id = $user->ID;
    $_email = $user->user_email;
    $user_info = json_encode(array("user_id"=>$_id,"user_email"=>$_email));

    $request_args = array(
        'httpversion' => '1.1',
        'headers' => 'Content-Type:application/json',
        'body' => $user_info,
    );
    $response = wp_safe_remote_post("https://myWebsite.com/endpoint", $request_args);
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        // request failed, handle the error.
        // Use $response->get_error_message(); to get error message
    } else {
        // It worked!!!
    }
    endif;
}
```

You'll notice `wp_safe_remote_post()` will return a [`WP_ERROR`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_error/) object if the request fails for some reason. It can be useful to use the `WP_Error::get_error_message()` to see what went wrong if the request fails.

#### Simple Debugging

Additionally, if you're new to PHP/WordPress and are working in a **non production** environment here's a trick to figure out if the callback is actually getting run and what the content's of the arguments are.

```
function identify_user( $user_login, $user ) {
  echo'<pre>';
  var_dump($user); 
  echo'</pre>';
  die();
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'identify_user', 10, 2);
```

This will print out the contents of `$user` to the screen then stop the res t of the execution. If that happens you know the problem is further down in the function body.

#### A Few Notes

It's worth noting that the `is_user_logged_in()` check is redundant because the `wp_login` is only fired at the very end of the [`wp_signon()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.4/src/wp-includes/user.php#L33) function meaning the user was literally just authenticated but I left it in the code above because redundant security is not the worst thing ever.

Also, you can probably just use `$user->ID` and `$user->user_email` directly instead of putting them into variables as you only use them the once. I left them in the code above though because it doesn't effect whether or not the code works.

#### Original answer's code

```
function identify_user( $user_login, $user ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ):
    $_id = $user->ID;
    $_email = $user->user_email;
    $user_info = json_encode(array("user_id"=>$_id,"user_email"=>$_email));
    $curl = curl_init("myWebsite.com/endpoint");
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $user_info);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_exec( $curl );
    curl_close( $curl );
    endif;
}
```

Comment: this feels right, but i haven't gotten it to work yet. i'm concerned that perhaps there's a plugin custom login that wp_login doesn't track.

Comment: you seem like you know what you're talking about, so i might be able to give you two answers today if you can get this one! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581802/woocommerce-add-to-cart-send-product-data-to-3rd-party-api

Comment: I've never worked with PHP so i've just been doing trial and error for hours

Comment: If you're in a dev environment try to see if you can dump the contents of the callback arguments to test if it's actually working. Using the snippet in my answer try replacing the `if()` block with `echo'<pre>'; var_dump($user); echo'</pre>'; die();`. That will dump the contents of the `$user` arg to the screen and stop all execution after.

Comment: I have the user object but the curl request is now failing?

Comment: my current question has the most updated solution attempt. i'll take a crack with your update now. thanks for the help!

Comment: placed a bounty on my other question and added the code where the error occurs plus the error:)